# Angular 6+ Monorepo with incremental build

Tags: angular, continuous-integration

We have a monorepo for our frontend application, which consist of three parts:

- user
- partner
- admin

Also we have some shared modules. Does any one know of a tool that can be configured to run specific commands based on commit changes? For example we do not need to build all projects on our CI build if we have only changed "user" project. We only need to rebuild all of them if we have changed something under "shared".

So we are looking for a working solutions to check commit files and take a decision based on path of this files what command should run on CI, for example if we have at least one change under src/projects/user than we should run "ng build user ...".

Answer (score 1):

You could check out nx. It offers some tools for monorepo projects including making automatic builds based on repository changes

https://nrwl.io/nx

Answer (score 0):

Rushjs by Microsoft is one open source alternative where you'd get incremental builds pretty much out of the box.

https://rushjs.io/

The tricky part is setting it up with CI, as you'd need to preserve a state somehow. I personally used docker images for that.

There's also lerna which can be combined with other tools, but you'd have to write/find more tooling to complement lerna for this type of thing.